# Passing path of file from node js to a python script

Tags: python, node.js

I constantly get this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0 and I do not know how to get rid of it. I want to pass the path where the audio is located to the python script so that it can be transcribed.

How is is possible to pass the path of the file to the python script?

I hope you can help me out.

Thank you very much.

Here is the Node.Js part

```
convertToText("public/uploads/test2.wav", "AudioText", "2020-05-11 16:04:22");
function convertToText(audioPath, filename, date) {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const scriptExecution = spawn("python", ["audioTranscribe.py"])
    var info = [audioPath, date];
    var jsonStr;
    console.log("Filename" + filename)
    console.log("Path ??" + audioPath)
    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        // saving transcribed files into transcriptions folder
        var srObj = JSON.parse(data.toString())
        jsonStr = data.toString();
        console.log("Was is das?? " + srObj["audio_text"])
        fs.writeFile('./transcriptions/' + filename + '.txt', srObj["audio_text"], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("File created!")
        })
    });
    scriptExecution.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(info));
    scriptExecution.stdin.end();

    //  return jsonStr;
}
```

Here is the python file

```
import re
import speech_recognition as sr
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import wave
import contextlib
import os.path
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    return json.loads(lines[0])


def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
        return o.__str__()


def convertToString():
    lines = read_in()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    text = ""
    duration = 0.0
    arr = []
    for item in lines:
        arr.append(item)
    audio = arr[0]
    print(arr[0])
    my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(my_path, arr[0])
    timestamp_begin = datetime.strptime(arr[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audio, 'r')) as f:
        frames = f.getnframes()
        rate = f.getframerate()

        # duration should be in seconds
        duration = frames / float(rate)
    with sr.AudioFile(path) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ko-kr')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    result = {'begin': timestamp_begin, 'end': timestamp_begin +
              timedelta(0, duration), 'audio_text': text}
    print(json.dumps(result, default=myconverter,
                     ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))


def main():
    convertToString()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am passing this audio path: public/uploads/test2.wav

I hope you can help me out.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the information via arguments, but it seems like there is a problem parsing the data with `JSON.parse`

Here's a minified working example:

```js
function convertToText(audioPath, filename, date) {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const scriptExecution = spawn("python", ["audioTranscribe.py", audioPath, filename, date])

    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        var srObj = JSON.parse(data.toString())
        console.log(srObj)
    })
}
convertToText("public/uploads/test2.wav", "AudioText", "2020-05-11 16:04:22");
```

```py
import json
import sys


def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    return json.loads(lines[0])


def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
        return o.__str__()


def convertToString():
    result = {'givenFilePath': sys.argv[0], "fileName": sys.argv[1], "date": sys.argv[2]}
    print(json.dumps(result))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    convertToString()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Will print:

```
{ date: 'AudioText',
  givenFilePath: 'audioTranscribe.py',
  fileName: 'public/uploads/test2.wav' }
```